# Getting { "message": null } 400 Bad Request Error in AWS API Gateway on enabling Authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway

I have created an API Gateway that will accept an SQL statement and will return its response. The SQL will be passed as a query parameter(q). Everything is working fine when Authorization is set to `None` as below:-

[image]

But on changing the Authorization to `AWS_IAM` as below I am getting an error - "{"message": null }" with the same API

[image]

I have explored the error `400 Bad Request` and found it is caused when the format of the query parameters is incorrect. And the same is in my case. Consider this below SQLs

```
SQL-1: q=SELECT * from student WHERE country = 'India'

SQL-2: q=SELECT * from student WHERE country is 'India'

SQL-3: q=SELECT * from student
```

I am getting an error when I am passing SQL-1 as a query parameter(q). But for SQL-2 and SQL-3 I am not getting that error. This indicates that API Gateway has some issue with `"="` in the query parameters.

Anyone know how can I solve this issue. Any suggestions or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try giving `country='India'` (avoid any whitespaces in between '=')? Let me know if that works?

Comment: @nachary I have tried it too. But it didn't work.

Comment: Could you show me what your POST request looks like (in the form of a url)?

Comment: POST Request:- https://xyz.amazonaws.com/V1/query?q=SELECT * from student WHERE country='India' It gives an error. However, it works after URL encoding it